# Make frame 80 percent height without use of constraints

Tags: swift, frame, subview, cgrect

I want to make my y value in my code below 80 percent of the height of the view controller without using constraints if that is possible. I would imagine it’s possible to create a var that tracks the percent of the view controller.

```
      import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    

  
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.backgroundColor = .blue

    imageView.frame = CGRect(x:  ,y: , width: , height: )
    view.addSubview(imageView)
  
 }
```

Comment: `imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the frame of the ViewController, which will give you the height and width properties.

```
let VCframe = self.view.frame 
let height = VCframe.height
let width = VCframe.width
```

You can implement the 80% logic with the values above.